# Programmatically write and read environment variables in Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core, console-application

The next code in Windows runs as expected and prints `Favorite Song = Hardwell, Spaceman`. But if I run it on Linux, it returns `Favorite Song = is null`. It also doesn't work with `EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine`. (console application net5)

What am I doing wrong? Why is Linux so weird?

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("FavoriteSong", "Hardwell, Spaceman ", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
        // test
        var song = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("FavoriteSong", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);

        Console.WriteLine("Favorite Song = {0}", song ?? "is null");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the [docs on `EnvironmentVariableTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environmentvariabletarget?view=net-5.0) ?  One could more rightfully ask, "why is Windows so weird?".

Comment: OK. Without EnvironmentVariableTarget, works. TXS

Comment: I will make a clarification on the question, and that generated my confusion. 
About this document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#configure-your-storage-connection-string

Should be: 
```basch
setx AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING "<yourconnectionstring>" /m
```

To be effective it works on Windows and Linux, since for Linux they say bach use export. 

About this suggestion: c# - How to set a global environment variable in .NET Core (user-wide or system-wide) - Stack Overflow, does not clarify the doubt.